# Lock the registry key for PDF files to prevent Browsers from hijacking it

Tags: windows

These days internet browsers are hijacking the PDF filetype.
I'm not interested in setting each browsers setting to disable their monopolizing behavior.
How do I lock the registry key for the PDF fileype so these browsers can't modify it?
What permissions should I set?

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.pdf

Comment: Don't, for any reason, at any time, change permissions on the registry. Down that path is destruction.

Comment: Which browsers are doing this, specifically?

Comment: chrome, firefox, and brave

Comment: Edge does it too. This is an interesting problem. I wonder if there's a utility that "keeps" your preferences for this. I suppose a startup entry that writes the registry keys may work, but that would only catch on startup or login.